# Heroku Rails PostgreSQL setup error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am setting up a Ruby on Rails app on Heroku. Heroku apparently does not support SQLite3, which is Rails' native database, but instead prefers PostgreSQL. So I'm switching production to that database.

### database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

### Gemfile

(relevant portion)

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

And the error I'm getting in the browser is:

> An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.

Digging into the application logs, it seems the error there is:

> `#<RuntimeError: Missing`secret_key_base`for 'production' environment, set this value in`config/secrets.yml`>

I've confirmed that the correct `DATABASE_URL` environment variable is set in my Heroku settings. And I've got `config/secrets.yml` in `.gitignore`. I don't really want to track this file. I'm using Rails 5.0.1. What am I doing wrong here? The database credentials are included in the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

Comment: Did you look at the application logs?

Comment: Do you mean `Activity Feed > Build Log`? I am not seeing any errors there.

Comment: You can actually remove the whole production section from `database.yml`. The default behaviour in Rails is to use `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` if its present. You can get the rails logs by running `$ heroku logs`

Comment: I'm using the web interface. Is there a terminal somewhere I'm missing to run that command?

Comment: Dude, you have to use a local shell to get anywhere with rails development...

Comment: I am using a local terminal. When I push my code to Github it is autodeployed to Heroku. Is there some way to access Heroku through the terminal?

Comment: Install the [heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) and follow the [rails quickstart guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5). You should also be using Postgres on your local machine. https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity

Comment: CLI. Awesome. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer I can give is **SWITCH EVERYTHING!** :-)

Seriously, you're going to encounter never-ending headaches maintaining two separate databases for two different environments. Save yourself a lot of heartache and switch your entire application to postgres.

Here's a small sampling of the issues you could encounter by having two separate databases:

1. Differences in supported data types.
2. Differences in SQL syntax.
3. Differences in performance optimization.

This is a great tutorial for making the transition: http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql?view=asciicast

Comment: How does switching the DB I use for local development help solve my issue on production?

Comment: It does'nt but it will save you a lot of greif down the line when you push something that passes your tests but blows up on Postgres.

Comment: The point is, don't do what you're doing at all. Scrap the attempt to make the production switch and instead use the tutorial mentioned to switch your entire application. I can pretty much guarantee you your migration process will go smoothly.

Comment: @wogsland It eliminates the chance that the error is caused by your code being incompatible w/ PostgresQL.

Comment: This does not answer the question - it just simple makes a cheap point about dev/prod parity which is not the root issue.

Comment: @max perhaps, but if somebody asks what the best way is to attempt jumping over the Grand Canyon on a pogo stick, the most logical and appropriate answer may very well be "don't attempt it at all".  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Start by setting up Postgres on your local machine.

- https://postgresapp.com/ (OS-X)
- https://www.postgresql.org/download/ (All other platforms)

You can setup a new Rails application with postgres by using the `--database=postgresql` option.

```
rails new myapp --database=postgresql
```

To convert an existing app add the `pg` gem to your gemfile.

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.19.0'
```

You want to use it in all environments so don't put it in a group.

This is all you need in your `database.yml`.

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development
test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test
```

Then setup your local DB by running

```
$ bin/rails db:create
$ bin/rails db:migrate
```

Most guides add a ton of other useless cruft out of ignorance - Heroku will setup the prod database by using the `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` env var so no production section is needed at all.

For `development` and `test` favor using `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` to setup passwords and usernames rather than writing it into `config/database.yml`. This avoids stupid developer wars and [separates the application from local configuration](https://12factor.net/config). The [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem and [direnv](https://direnv.net/) make this very simple to acheive.

- [Getting Started with Rails 5.x on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#write-your-app)
- [Configuring Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database)

Comment: The `rails new myapp database=postgresql` command appears to still create it with SQLite3?

Comment: So I fixed that, but `bin/rails db:create` is failing.

Comment: Giving up on local development for the time being, I pushed it to production but I'm still getting the same error regarding a RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base`.

Comment: Its `--database=postgresql` not `database=postgresql`. In shell commands `--` means that you are passing a key/value option.

Comment: `secret_key_base` has nothing to do with Postgres.  Its the key used to sign cookies - its set via `config/secrets.yml` or `ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]`. I would try starting from scratch since it seems like you have followed a really bad set of instructions and totally botched your rails app.

Comment: Follow the quickstart guide instead. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5

Comment: I'm currently ignoring `config/secrets.yml`. Is there any way to get around that? Like can I make multiple files for production and development so I can just ignore the development one?

Comment: Check `config/secrets.yml` into git and use env vars for any sensitive info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136279/discussion-between-max-and-wogsland).